# Firefox canvas not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas

I have this radial progress view, inside a canvas. Chrome renders it fine, but Firefox doesn't.

Please help me fix it, fast.

I guess the problem is with this:

```
this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out';
```

http://codepen.io/vahidseo/pen/qBFcv

Comment: It seems to work on my computer. And why do you thing that's the problem?

Comment: Visit it on chrome, and you'll see. On Firefox, the arcs aren't showing. please help, @vlas

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

```
this.ctx.restore ();//must be put before adding the text.
```